# Unable to request signatures until this application has completed the initial key generation

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

When I am trying to compile the WordPress app for blackberry with Ant tools in command line. some error happens like the following, I have already installed the singing key in eclipse.  I don't know where is the problem. I am using the BB SDK5.0.

please help me.

> [rapc] adding: WordPress-15.cod(in = 73752) (out= 73752)(stored 0%) 
>    [rapc] adding: WordPress-16.cod(in = 78672) (out= 78672)(stored 0%) 
>    [rapc] adding: WordPress-17.cod(in = 75156) (out= 75156)(stored 0%) 
>    [rapc] adding: WordPress-18.cod(in = 65592) (out= 65592)(stored 0%) 
>    [rapc] No errors.
>
> sign:
>    [copy] Copying 27 files to E:\Develop\BBWP\WordpressBB\release\os50\sign
>
> [echo] Please sign the .cod file located at E:/Develop/BBWP/WordpressBB/release/os50/sign 
>    [java] 2012-11-06 18:05:00:0032 : SignatureTool Started
>
> [java] Finding Files... 
>    [java] Failed.
>    [java] **Unable to request signatures until this application has completed the initial key generation.**
>
> BUILD FAILED 
>   E:\Develop\BBWP\WordpressBB\build\build.xml:128: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
>   E:\Develop\BBWP\WordpressBB\build\build_single.xml:136: Java returned: -1

At first I checked many times that I am sure i have installed and activated my singing key.   later i tried to use the same singing key for each version of Blackberry SDK, it didn't work well. seems cannot use the same singing key for all SDKs, so I ordered many keys for different versions of SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You need valid and activated set of BlackBerry signature keys. Read more about signing keys here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/code_signing_1977871_11.html

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html

You could request them here:

https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked many times that I am sure i have installed and activated my singing key.